# What does "uniq" mean here

Tags: uniq

Hi folks this is a question given to me as assignment. Please help me to understand it.

> Consider a new operator `|||`. It will take the output of the previous program and
>   pass it on as input to three different programs. Give a program `triplepipe.c` for
>   implementing the following command:
>
> ls –l | uniq ||| grep ^d, grep ^-, grep ^p.
>
> Don't use `popen()` library call, `system()` library call, or temporary files.

I know what the `uniq` command is. But what is it doing beside `ls -l`, which gives a list of unique items anyway, right? What is `uniq` adding here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there can't be duplicate entries in a directory, so `ls -l` won't have any duplicated lines (except perhaps in some extremely unusual situation; I'm not positive about that). I think the `uniq` is useless here and is probably a mistake.